# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/hibernate/cache/redis/SingletonRedisRegionFactory.start(

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, redis

I am trying to integrate "hibernate-redis" as Hibernate 2nd level cache provider in spring-boot application. I was following the instructions in the github page.

https://github.com/hibernate-redis/hibernate-redis

But, the application fails with following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/hibernate/cache/redis/SingletonRedisRegionFactory.start(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions;Ljava/util/Properties;)V is abstract
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.ehcache.Application.main(Application.java:27) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method org/hibernate/cache/redis/SingletonRedisRegionFactory.start(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/SessionFactoryOptions;Ljava/util/Properties;)V is abstract
    at org.hibernate.cache.redis.SingletonRedisRegionFactory.start(SingletonRedisRegionFactory.java) ~[hibernate-redis-1.6.6.jar:na]
```

MY project configuration as follows,

pom.xml **"UPDATED THE DEPENDENCIES TO MINIMUM"**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Cache-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.hibernate-redis</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Application.properties

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# Set here configurations for the database connection
# Connection url for the database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
# Username and password
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true`enter code here`
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
# H2 Configuration
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Caching
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.redis.SingletonRedisRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region_prefix=hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path=hibernate-redis.properties
```

hibernate-redis.properties

```
##########################################################
#
# properties for hibernate-redis
#
##########################################################

# Redis Server for hibernate 2nd cache
redis.host=localhost
redis.port=6379

# use redis-sentinel cluster as opposed to a single redis server (use only if not using host/port)
# redis.sentinels = host1:26379,host2:26379,host3:26379
# redis.masterName = mymaster

# redis.timeout=2000
# redis.password=

# database for hibernate cache
# redis.database=0
redis.database=1

# Hibernate 2nd cache default expiry (seconds)
redis.expiryInSeconds=120

# expiry of hibernate.common region (seconds) 
redis.expiryInSeconds.hibernate.common=0

# expiry of hibernate.book region (seconds) 
redis.expiryInSeconds.hibernate.book=4
```

The application works fine without cache configs. Does anyone have an idea. Thank you!

The project can be found in the location.
https://github.com/janitham/SpringBoot-Hibernate-Ehcache/tree/SpringBoot-Hibernate-RedisCache

Comment: Remove the `hibernate-core` dependency.

Comment: That didn't work. I have updated the latest pom.xml with minimal dependencies.

Comment: Then your version of `hibernate-redis` isn't compatible with this version of Hibernate. Checking the website this is for Hibernate 4.2 and 4.3, not for later versions. [This](https://github.com/debop/hibernate-redis) seems to be a compatible (and the original) version.

Comment: @M.Deinum That is correct. hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager had overridden with compatible hibernate version and now it works fine. Thanks for your help.